# Transform a CSS3 navigation menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I found a wonderful tutorial for what I think is a pretty decent menu. I'm trying to turn it into a vertical dropdown one similar to : http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/699_nav/navCode/nav.html or http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/?search_index=3

I just want the list to drop down instead of coming from the side. I've tried what I thought would solve it and targeted the li elements to display inline and so on but I cannot make it work, either what I change has no effect or causes it to be a jumbled mess.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcYJj/)

CSS

```
#thisNav{
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px;
    background:#bada55;
}

#thisNav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#thisNav ul li{
    /*child elements positioned absolutley will be relative to this*/
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;

}

#thisNav a{
    color: ghostwhite;
    padding: 12px 0px;
    /*fill hori space*/
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
/*apply transition to background property, taking 1s to change it
*/
    transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -moz-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -webkit-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;
    -o-transition:padding 1s, background 1s;

    font-family:tahoma;

    font-size:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left:20px;
}

/*hover pseduo class*/
#thisNav a:hover{
    /*
    RGBA background for transparancy:
    last number(0.05) is the transparency
    */
    padding-left:35px;
    background: RGBA(255,255,255,0.05);
    color:#fff;
}

#thisNav ul li:hover ul{
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: block;

}

#thisNav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    width: 304px;
}

#thisNav ul ul li{
    width: 150px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-top: 0;
    float:left;

}

#thisNav ul ul li a{
    color:#000000;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:none;
}

#thisNav ul ul li a:hover {
    color:#929292;
}

#thisNav span {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
}
#thisNav a:hover span {
    background: #7d2c41;
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
}

/*Horizontal line*/
#thisNav span:before {
    content:"";
    width:12px;
    height:2px;
    background:#3a3b3b;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:5px;
}
/*Vertical line*/
#thisNav span:after {
    content:"";
    width:2px;
    height:12px;
    background:#3a3b3b;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    position:top;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav id = "thisNav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><span></span>one</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"><span></span>two</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tryout this: http://jsfiddle.net/BcYJj/7/

Set `height` on main `ul`, so the green background gets painted (otherwise its 0px high):

```
#thisNav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Floated `li`s, so the main `li`s are listed horizontal:

```
#thisNav ul li{
/*child elements positioned absolutley will be relative to this*/
position: relative;
border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;

float: left;
```

}

Removed `width` from sub `ul`s, relocated it (`left`, `top`) and set the `z-index`. Set `top`/`left` to make it appear below instead right to the menu item. Set the `z-index` due to a visibility error:

```
#thisNav ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 40px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    /*width: 304px;*/
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Edit**
removed unnecessary step, updated link and added explanations ;)

I hope this helps!

Comment: That's brilliant! :)  What was the main issue?  I notice you didn't change the display to inline etc etc?

Comment: Glad you like it! See the added explanations.

Comment: Thanks again, it helps a great deal! :)  I do now have a small minor issue.  I'm not sure if it can be fixed.  If you set the width of the main to 500px for example and pretend that that is the page width at 100% and then add 5 or so etc items, my list has quite a few.  When they scroll/wrap the page weird things happen.  Can you suggest a solution please?  I'm thinking of either adding an extra level to the drop down or maybe something else.  I guess that maybe this nav isn't designed for many list items.

Comment: If the menu may not span multiple rows (which is common), I think you have to either use smaller sizes (item-size, font-size,...) or, as you said, use sub-menus. I would probably go with the submenus.

Comment: Cheers Warappa, much appreciated.

Comment: would you be able to help me with the hidden 3rd level please? http://jsfiddle.net/6TGaf/ it's always showing and not waiting for a hover

Comment: Use ´#nav ul li:hover>ul{
    /*diplay when hovered*/
    display: block;
}´ - notice the `>` in the selector. With it this rule only applies to a `ul` which is a **direct** child of a hovered `li`. http://jsfiddle.net/6TGaf/12/

Answer (score 1):

[Changed some css in your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcYJj/5/)

```
#thisNav ul ul{
    border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#thisNav ul ul li{
    width: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Bastian, thanks for taking the time to look at it.  Is it possible to get one and two next to each other?

Comment: for sure it is. look at the fiddle of Warappa. he has made a more complete one.